# Dispatch another action / call another reducer within a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using React with Redux and have ran into a situation where I want one of my reducers to dispatch another action, but am not sure how.

Created using the `createSlice` function, I have a slice for authentication and one for modals. I would like to call the `hideModal` action from within the `login` reducer of my authentication slice, to cleanly hide the login modal once submitted.

The reason I cannot just call `dispatch(login())` immediately followed by `dispatch(hideModal())` is that I need to find out if there are any errors in the form data first, which can only be known inside the `[login.fulfilled]` reducer, as `login` is an asynchronous thunk, created using `createAsyncThunk`.

I understand that this is somewhat of an anti-pattern in React, so was wondering what is the best way to achieve this?

The only solution I have so far is for the `modalSlice` to listen for `login.fulfilled` as part of its `extraReducers` object. But this is quite messy.

Any help would be appreciated, do let me know if this question is not clear enough, I will try and clarify. Thank you

### Authentication Slice

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: {
        loggedIn: false,
        userId: null,
        errors: []
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            if (action.payload.success) {
                state.loggedIn = true;
                state.userId = action.payload.userId;
                state.errors = [];
            } else {
                state.errors = action.payload.errors;
            }
        },
// Omitting rest of slice
```

### Modal Slice

```
export const modalSlice = createSlice({
    name: "modal",
    initialState: {
        current: ""
    },
    reducers: {
        hideModal: (state) => {
            state.current = "";
        },
        showModal: (state, action) => {
            state.current = action.payload;
        }
    },

    // Possible solution: Works but quite messy 
    // and copies code from above rather than calling hideModal
    extraReducers: {
        [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            if (action.payload.success) {
                state.current = "";
            }
        },
// Omitting rest of slice
```

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I cannot just call dispatch(login()) immediately followed by dispatch(hideModal()) is that I need to find out if there are any errors in the form data first, which can only be known inside the login reducer.

Can't you do a check for any errors before the next dispatch? You have access to the redux store inside of your component

```
dispatch(authLogin);
if (this.state.auth.errors) { // or however you are connecting to your store
  // do error handling stuff
} else {
 dispatch(closeModal);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but as login is asynchronous, using react-thunk middleware, the return value can only be seen reliably in the `login.fulfilled` reducer